# Why is there a difference between printing in console and displaying file content in label

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter, label

I was trying to read .txt file in python, it works perfectly in console but when I try to put this in Label (tkinter) the text structure is wrong. Information is correct but the lines placement is slightly off which makes it difficult to read

I tried different widgets and printing text line by line.

```
def bada_search():
    aircraft_search = bada_entry.get()
    try:
        with open("BADA\\" + str(aircraft_search) + "__.PTF", "rt") as file:
            dane = file.read()
            bada_window= Toplevel()
            bada_dane= Label(bada_window, text= dane).pack()
            print(dane)
    except:
        print("Aircraft not found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about text alignments. You need to use a monospaced font, for example `Consolas`:

```
def bada_search():
    aircraft_search = bada_entry.get()
    try:
        with open("BADA\\" + str(aircraft_search) + "__.PTF", "rt") as file:
            dane = file.read()
            bada_window= Toplevel()
            bada_dane= Label(bada_window,text= dane,font="Consolas 9").pack()
            print(dane)
    except:
        print("Aircraft not found")
```